# Vertx + MongoClient Singleton

Tags: mongodb, vert.x

I have started working with Vertex and emerged the next question. Is it correct to apply the pattern "Singleton", to work with the `MongoClient` object?

Something like this:

```
class Mongo {
    private static volatile MongoClient mongoclient = null;

    private Mongo(){};

    public static MongoClient getInstance() {
        if (mongoclient == null) {
            synchronized(Mongo.class) {
                if (mongoclient == null)
                    mongoclient = MongoClient.createShared(vertx, config);
            }
        }
        return mongoclient;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the vertx Mongodb client as it's shown in the documentation? http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-mongo-client/java/

Comment: At this Vertx example, makes something similar:

https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-auth/blob/master/vertx-auth-mongo/src/test/java/io/vertx/ext/auth/mongo/test/MongoBaseTest.java.

I was asking if it was a good decision to apply this pattern.

Comment: This is what [I was replied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53286404/pattern-for-using-properly-mongoclient-in-vert-x) a couple of months ago and I'm quite happy so far.