# Pattern for using properly MongoClient in Vert.x

Tags: vert.x

I feel quite uncomfortable with the `MongoClient` class, certainly because I don't exactly understand what it is and how it works.

> The first call to `MongoClient.createShared` will actually create the
>   pool, and the specified config will be used.
>
> Subsequent calls will return a new client instance that uses the same
>   pool, so the configuration won’t be used.

Does that mean that the pattern should be:

1. In startup function, to create the pool, we make a call

   ```
   mc = MongoClient.createShared(vx, config, "poolname");
   ```

   Is the returned value `mc` important for this first call if it succeeds? What is its value if the creation of the pool fails? The documentations doesn't say. There is a socket exception if `mongod` is not running, but what about the other cases?
2. In another place in the code (another verticle, for example), can we write `mc = MongoClient.createShared(vx, new JsonObject(), "poolname");` to avoid to systematically need to access shared objects.
3. Again, In another verticle where we need to access the database, should we define `MongoClient mc`

   - as a class field in which case it will be released to the pool only in the `stop()` method, or
   - shouldn't it be a variable populated with `MongoClient.createShared(...)` and de-allocated with `mc.close()` once we don't need the connection any more in order release it again to the pool ?

What I would write is as follows

```
// Main startup Verticle
import ...

public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
  ...      
  @Override
  public void start(Future<Void> sf) throws Exception {
     ...
     try {
       MongoClient.createShared(vx, config().getJsonObject("mgcnf"),  "pool");
     }
     catch(Exception e) {
       log.error("error error...");
       sf.fail("failure reason");
       return;
     }
     ...
     sf.complete();
  }
  ...some other methods
}
```

and then, in some other place

```
public class SomeVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    public void someMethod(...) {
    ...
    // use the database:
    MongoClient mc = MongoClient.createShared(vx,  new JsonObject(),  "pool");
        mc.save(the_coll, the_doc, res -> {
            mc.close();
            if(res.succeeded()) {
                ...
            }
            else {
                ...
            }   
       }
       ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Does that make sense ? Yet, this is not what is in the examples that I could find around the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about pools. Don't use them. They don't do what you think they do.

In your `start` method of any verticle, set a field (what you call a class field, but you really mean instance field) on the inheritor of `AbstractVerticle` to `MongoClient.createShared(getVertx(), config)`. Close the client in your `stop` method. That's it.

The other exceptions you'll see are:

- Bad username/password
- Unhealthy cluster state
- The Java driver has a limit of 500 or 1,000 connections (depending on version), you'll receive an exception if you exceed this connection count

Both will be propagated up from the driver wrapped in a `VertxException`.